# Creating a "Data entry table" parameter - Arcpy tool scripts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1

I want to create an Arcpy tool script that takes values from a 2-column table placed in the tool itself, which is filled by the user, and stores these values in a real table.

In order to do so, I have created a "Record Set" parameter in the script properties. This RecordSet has a data schema taken from an existing table and is composed by 2 columns (param1, param2) (see image below).

[image]

Once I execute the tool, the following form appears:
[image]

As you can see, the tool has a table where the user can write any values, entering them directly to the table's rows (red dots in the image).

I have come to the solution of getting these values and storing them to a real table using arcpy:

tb = arcpy.CopyRows_management(in_recordset, "table_path")

And there is no problem with this, because it is done quite well.

However, this solution turns out to not being user friendly: In the first place, the upper box with the string "Script::t" on it can't be modified because when doing so, tool crashes. Secondly, one must click first to the "+" button to create a new row, and then fill the spaces. Additionally, while doing so, some cells turn in white and I have to "battle" a little bit with some clicks in order to have them all filled.

So, my question(s):

**What is the upper box with the string "Script::t" intended for? And can it be taken out somehow?**

**And most important: is this the most apt solution to create the tool I need? Are there other options to insert a table to the tool by using another kind of parameter than "Record Set" parameter?**

Hope I have explaied myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "upper box" is something you cannot remove as that is the mechanism that allows you to enter a row into the table. If you have a look at other standard geo-processing tools you'll find that this is the way things are done. I have not found or can think of a tool that does not have an "upper box".

So you are wiring up an interface to an existing script, this is a *script tool*. If you explore a [python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) you'll discover a more powerful method of running python scripts. You create the parameters in the code itself rather than wire up an interface to existing code. A parameter available in python toolbox is the [ValueTable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E2BAA5D4440D41D6AAB948922186905A). I wrote a simple [document](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-3210) over on geonet that describes this process. You have considerable control over what it can do, although I still think you can't get away from that "upper box", I'm sure there is some design philosophy behind it.